# Could not open input file: artisan in Docker command

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to create Docker file for my Laravel rest Api with Vue.js in the backend Docker file when I tried to run php artisan serve I am getting the error below.

Could not open input file: artisan
The command 'php artisan serve' returned a non-zero code: 1

```
FROM php:7.2.19-fpm

RUN mkdir ./my-project/

WORKDIR /my-project
COPY . ./my-project/

RUN apt-get update

RUN cd my-project

FROM composer:1.7 as vendor

COPY database/ database/

COPY composer.json composer.json
COPY composer.lock composer.lock

RUN composer install \
    --ignore-platform-reqs \
    --no-interaction \
    --no-plugins \
    --no-scripts \
    --prefer-dist


RUN ["php", "artisan", "serve"]

EXPOSE 8000
```

Comment: Is it possible that the second `FROM` negates the `WORKDIR`? Could you try it out? Also the copy probably

Comment: Nothing before the `FROM composer...` line has any effect in this Dockerfile.  Specifying a new `FROM` image starts anew with just the contents of that base image.  Usually this is used for a multi-stage build where you `COPY --from=...` artifacts that got built in an earlier stage.

Answer (score -1):

Use full paths for `WORKDIR` and `COPY`

Give this a try:

```
FROM php:7.2-cli
COPY . /usr/src/myapp
WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp
CMD [ "php", "./your-script.php" ]
```

Also, as mentioned above, the second `FROM` starts a new build stage for `VENDOR`.